# Dividing a mesh into tetrahedra?

Tags: algorithm, math, model, 3d, geometry

Let's say I have some arbitrary set of points connected by faces and lines in order to make a closed polyhedron. Is there any algorithm that can divide such a mesh into a group of tetrahedra?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can look to construct a constrained Delaunay triangulation (i.e. tetrahedralisation) of the points in `R^3`, where the constraints are a list of edges and triangular faces.

Be aware though -- in dimensions higher than two it is not always possible to form such a constrained triangulation directly! A good example is the [Schonhardt Polyhedron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sch%C3%B6nhardt_polyhedron). To deal with such polyhedra it's necessary to 'split' the constraints by introducing additional vertices. As I understand it, it is still an open area of research to determine the "best" way to do this, although a range of heuristic approaches have been suggested.

You might be interested in [Jonathan Shewchuk's](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/) research/software in this area, specifically, his papers:

- [Constrained Delaunay Tetrahedralizations and Provably Good Boundary Recovery](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/cdtbasic.pdf)
- [Updating and Constructing Constrained Delaunay and Constrained Regular Triangulations by Flips](http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~jrs/papers/cdtflip.pdf)

Address some of the issues of higher-dimensional constrained triangulations.

Also, I've assumed that your problem is non-trivial -- with a set of constraints that define a non-convex polyhedron. In the case of convex constraints these should be recovered directly just by computing the unconstrained Delaunay triangulation, which is guaranteed to exists in any dimensionality.

Comment: Are there any good sources that could help me how to implement the methods you outlined?